# Chrome sync error

Tags: google-chrome

I just obtained a new Windows 8 computer, and when trying to sync my old Google Chrome settings, bookmarks, etc., I get a sync error message. What do you do to change the passphrase so I can properly sync my settings?

Answer (score 0):

You might have changed your google account password, If you have done so, then try to insert the previously used password in  sync passphrase, Hope this will solve your problem.